# Copy some folders from one TFS project into the other

Tags: tfs, copy, projects

I have a single TFS server with 2 different team projects - Project 1 and project 2. Project 2 is completely empty. Now, I want to copy some ASP.NET project 1 folders into project 2. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can rightclick on the team project in Source Control and then select Branch (2008) or Branching and Merging -> Branch (2010).

In the dialog you see specify that TP2 is the target for your branch.

Answer (score 0):

Check out project 1 and project 2, on the local system copy the folders you wish to copy from p1 to p2.  From the source control explorer add the copied folders to source control. Check in changes.

AFAIK there is no way to make "links" to existing files or folders in TFS.